# Starting with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am new in selenium and i learned the concept things in selenium but i haven't experience and proper knowledge that how to start automation of a web application. I need few tips so i can start the automation in a proper way like which framework to use.

it will be grateful help that someone provide me the guideline of start automation in selenium web driver through java. Below is the application link that i wanna start automation.

http://talentrack.in/

Please review the application and please suggest me to startup guidelines.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am answering this question as i had solved one query regarding this website.
So start your Automation scripting with sign-up page, filling the details of the form. 
Page object model is very useful for this type of sites.
So basically create test cases with pom.xml i.e maven. and create everything by calling methods i.e. for every page create a different class and anything you do on that page, the method related to it should be in that class.

See the below example..

My test is

```
//MAximize the Screen
driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
//Go to Gmail Login Page
SignInPage SignInPage = WebUtils.GoToSignInPage(driver);
//Sign in to Login page -Send Username 
SignInPage.SendkeysMethodForSignInPAge(driver, By.cssSelector("input[id='Email']") , "kishanpatelllll.8@gmail.com" );
//Click on Next
SignInPage.ClickToLogin(driver, By.cssSelector("input[id='next']"));
//Wait for password field to be visible
SignInPage.WaitForElementTobeVisible(driver, By.cssSelector("input[id='Passwd'][type='password']"));
```

So when i call the method SendkeysMethodForSignInPAge i wont write it in @Test.

See SendkeysMethodForSignInPAge method: public class SignInPage {

```
public void SendkeysMethodForSignInPAge(WebDriver driver, By by, String s) {
WebUtils.Sendkeys(driver,by,s);
```

}

I created a new class and there i defined it. This is basic flow. Hope you can relate this. Now you create a common method Sendkeys(WebDriver driver, By by, String s ) in class WebUtils which will be used by each page object class here it will be called by SendkeysMethodForSignInPAge Method.

Reply to me, if your are still stuck. Happy Learning :-)

Comment: Thanks for providing such a wonderful help, i will start and will contact you if i am stuck anywhere. Really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Yes anytime. Enjoy. :-)

Comment: @ Kishan, I am still stuck, can you please elevate in brief. Or u can give me an example of my website signup page. It will be very helpful for me

Comment: Where are you stuck ? Post it